# In HBase is it possible to set CELL level TTL during bulk upload?

Tags: hbase

I think it is possible to set cell level TTL using [mutation](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Mutation.html#setTTL(long))

However, is there a way to set cell level TTL when doing bulk upload?

Comment: Anyone got any success in this ?